# How to automating root filesystem cleaning without intramfs?

Tags: linux, embedded, filesystems

I have an embedded device that on extremely rare occasions will have a dirty root filesystem. System-D will halt boot with:

```
Give root password for maintainence
(or type control-D to continue):
```

These situations are very rare and can be solved by doing the following after entering the root password:

```
# mount -o remount,ro /
# fsck /dev/mmcblk1p3
```

Is there anyway to automate this or even try to perform the cleaning when the filesystem is in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite systemd emergency mode by editing the appropriate Unit file (or just `systemctl edit emergency.service`).

You can then add something like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "mount -o remount,ro / && fsck /dev/mmcblk1p3 && /bin/systemctl reboot"
```

Comment: This is perfect, it is rare enough that I am ok if this fails and causes the device to spin